# jQuery UI resizable handles in stable v1.9.0 vs legacy 1.8.24

Tags: jquery-ui, resizable

This *might* be a duplication of [Custom Resizable Handles in JQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958419/custom-resizable-handles-in-jquery-ui), but that post talks about the handle *not* being a child element of the resizable element, and it doesn't specify which *version* of jQuery UI.

The [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) states that custom handles can be defined as follows:

> The following keys are supported: { n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw }. The value of any specified should be a jQuery selector matching the child element of the resizable to use as that handle.

In my code, the handle *is* a child element of the resizable element, and the jQuery is as follows:

```
$("#searchbar_container").resizable({ 
    handles: {w: '#searchbar_handle_top'},
    maxWidth: 445,
    minWidth: 20,
    start: function(event, ui) {},
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#searchbar_container").css('height', '');
    } 
});
```

I can get it to work with the legacy version of jQuery UI (1.8.24): [link](http://www.pinksy.co.uk/resizable/resizable1.html)
...but not with the "stable" version of jQuery UI (1.9.0) and the exact same code: [link](http://www.pinksy.co.uk/resizable/resizable2.html) . Both pages use the same version of jQuery core (1.8.2).

The stable version of jQuery UI produces the following console error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: , jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2

Does anyone think I'm doin' it wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with jquery 1.9.0, resizable with args seems to be broken in the new release. Reverting back to a legacy release until it is fixed.

Comment: The only bug that I've seen reported involves XHTML 5 ([here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8639))

Comment: Thanks David. I'm going to stick with the legacy version. Incidentally, I've found that some of the args do work in 1.9.0, such as maxWidth, minWidth, and possibly some others (I haven't tested them all), but the handles arg is definitely broken. If I get chance, I'll raise a jQuery ticket for it.