# Use an HR tag to resize a textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

I'm trying to create a resizable textarea with an horizontal rule as handle (similar to Stackoverflow editor).

I'm trying with :

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea class='editor'></textarea>
</div>
```

and

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $(".editor")
            .wrap("<div class='resizable'></div>'")
            .parent()
            .append("<hr class='resizer ui-resizable-s'/>");    

        $(".resizable").resizable({
            handles: {
                s: $(".resizer").get()
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But this does not works. Nothing happens actually.

How to fix this?

FYI, there is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/sz5z5pcd/) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Problem is diagnosed and solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958419/custom-resizable-handles-in-jquery-ui?rq=1

Comment: thanks @BenRondeau, but as you can see in my own answer, it's a jsFiddle issue... not a jQuery (the link you provided is very close to what I wrote)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, actually my code is working if I inject manually jQuery and jQueryUI.

Probably a bug with jsFiddle.

The updated jsFiddle : [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/sz5z5pcd/1/)

To be more precise, my first attempt was to add jQuery and jQuery UI using jsfiddle:

[image]

This did not work. The chrome console showed:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined$.widget._mouseDown @ jquery-ui.js:648(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:582jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-compat-git.js:4894jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery-compat-git.js:4551 67jquery-ui.js:656
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

But if I manually include these resources:

[image]
[image]

- `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css`
- `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js`
- `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js`

it works as expected.

Comment: @Stewartside: the full working code is in the question. Only references of external ressources has changed (using jsFiddle UI, not using tags), that's why I didn't duplicate the code from the question

Comment: @Stewartside: you're right. I updated the answer with more details